# Oracle XE not binding on IP4 port 1521

Tags: database, linux, networking, oracle11g, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Oracle 11g XE installed in Ubuntu 12.4 and facing difficulty with getting the Oracle to bind on a TCP port. The IP6 binding seems to be fine but not the IP4 (tcp 0.0.0.0:1521).

Here is the oracle-xe status:

```
root@pearBox:~# /etc/init.d/oracle-xe status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-JUN-2013 15:08:34

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                06-JUN-2013 15:06:42
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 52 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/pearBox/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=pearBox)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=pearBox)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Netstat results:

```
root@pearBox:~# netstat -ntpl

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      914/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1859/apache2    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      608/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22447                :::*                    LISTEN      1757/xe_d000_XE 
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1655/tnslsnr    
tcp6       0      0 :::1521                 :::*                    LISTEN      1655/tnslsnr    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      608/sshd
```

And the listener configuration:

```
root@pearBox:~# cat /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pearBox)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

I changed the hostname to "HOST = 127.0.0.1" and it is binding on localhost, but I am not able to access the Oracle instance from the network!

```
root@pearBox:~# netstat -ntpl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      914/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1859/apache2    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1521          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2339/tnslsnr    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      608/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::21121                :::*                    LISTEN      2443/xe_d000_XE 
tcp6       0      0 :::22
```

I would appreciate if you could help to get this issue resolved.

Comment: I am also having the same problem , how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found this post, I had the same issue. It was the result of changing my hostname post-installation. I was able to remedy the situation by updating the hostname in both:

/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

and

/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora

Comment: If you have another question please do not answer. Make a comment or a new question

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to take a look on the firewall rules -> https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing the hostname worked for me as I found a mismatch by checking:

1. uname -a
2. listener log : log.xml
3. /etc/hosts

I added the full host name with the domain

Appreciated the help as I've been searching internet posts for a week before I got this reference.